# Как искать по части слова или последовательности букв

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Необходимо осуществлять поиск в монго, но не только по целому слову, а и по нескольким буквам. То есть если в коллекции есть запись с полем “Иванов Василевич Сергей” – то нужно возвращать ее при совпадении как со словом целиком, допустим – “Иванов”, так и с частью слова “вано”. С поиском по полному совпадению проблем нет, сделал как-то так

```
module.exports.personGetAllWithParams = options => {
    return Persons.paginate(
      {
        $text: { $search: options.search }        
      },
      options
    );
 }
```

Но по части слова не ищет. Возможно, можно это дело описать через регулярное выражение? Как-то же такой поиск делают…уже достаточно долго ищу и не могу ничего подобного найти

Answer (score 0):

Получилось сделать так. Пришлось указать каждое поле отдельно, а не по индексу, но работает как нужно - наверное при большом объеме базы это будет не так быстро как с индексами.

```
return Persons.paginate(
      {        
        $or: [
          { name: { $regex: options.search, $options: "i" } },
          { lastname: { $regex: options.search, $options: "i" } },
          { middlename: { $regex: options.search, $options: "i" } }
        ]
      },
      options
    );
```

Comment: В общем то все правильно написано. Для ускорения mongodb можно заставить с помощью db.collection.createIndex индексировать определенные поля.

Comment: Ну да, так и сделано было в первом варианте, но в таком случае в $text нет свойства $regex и по части слова, нескольким буквам не ищет - ищет только по слову целиком